# d3 Multiline Graph Update

Tags: javascript, graph, d3.js, multiline

I have a multiline graph that displays 10 series of data, I am trying to get the lines to update with new data but for some reason I can't get that happening.
The transition with the new data is working for the points on the lines so I assume I am not selecting the right elements but for the life of me I can't figure out where my mistake is.
At one point I had one line changing which indicated it was only updating from the first index of the data array.
Any insight would be appreciated:

Initial Series creation-

```
    var series = svg.selectAll(".series")
        .data(seriesData)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "series");

series.append("path")
        .attr("id", function (d) {
            return d.name;
        })
        .attr("stay", "false")
        .attr("class", "line")

        .attr("d", function (d) {
            d.line = this;
            return line(d.values);
        })
        .attr("opacity", ".2")
        .on("click", function () {
            fadeOuts(this);
        })
        .style("stroke", function (d) {
            return strokeCol;
        })
        .style("stroke-width", "4px")
        .style("fill", "none");
```

Update function:
This is where I am stuck, the points respond to the new data but the paths do not.

```
    series.data(newseriesData);
    series.selectAll("path")
            .attr("id", function (d) {
                return d.name;
            })
            .attr("d", function (d) {
                d.line = this;
                return line(d.values);
            })
            .attr("opacity", ".2")
            .on("click", function () {
                fadeOuts(this);
            })
            .style("stroke", function (d) {
                return strokeCol;
            })
            .style("stroke-width", "4px")
            .style("fill", "none");
    series.selectAll(".point")
            .data(function (d) {
                return d.values;
            })
            .transition()
            .attr("cx", function (d) {
                return x(d.label) + x.rangeBand() / 2;
            })
            .attr("cy", function (d) {
                return y(d.value);
            })
            .style("fill", function (d) {
                return color(d.name);
            })
            .style("stroke", "grey")
            .style("stroke-width", "2px")
            .on("mouseover", function (d) {
                showPopover.call(this, d);
            })
            .on("mouseout", function (d) {
                removePopovers();
            })
```

Yes this is a university project, this is the last piece of work in a solid 50+ hour effort on this and I'd just like to get it knocked out.

Comment: Try `series.select("path")` instead of `series.selectAll("path")`.

Comment: Yeah you're right, had meant to make a comment last night when I got it working. Thanks for that! Kind of counterintuitive as it seems like you would be iterating over a collection and updating, my D3 kung fu is not strong I guess.

Comment: I'll add that as an answer with some explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that instead of `series.selectAll("path")` you should use `series.select("path")`. Remember that `series` is already a selection, and the subselection is done for each element in it. You've appended exactly one element to each of the selection, so `.select()` is fine and no `.selectAll()` is required.

The main difference this makes is that `.select()` inherits the data from the parent selection, while `.selectAll()` doesn't -- when doing `.selectAll()` the data is simply not updated and therefore no change occurs.